# How can I display the time passed since a comment was created instead of the creation date?

Tags: 8, theming, datetime, comments

how to personalize my comments ?

- I want to display since when the comment was created instead of the date.
- I want to display the comment ID with the link "permalink".

Can you help me ? Thank you

`comment--field-article-commentaire.html.twig` :

```
<article{{ attributes.addClass('js-comment comment--field-article-commentaire') }}>
  <div class="row card rounded-lg mt-4">
    <div class="card-header p-2 m-0 h6">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="timeline-icon mt-1 mr-3 mb-1 ml-1 float-left">
          {{ drupal_entity('user', comment.uid.target_id, 'comment') }}
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="mb-2">
            {{ permalink }}
          </div>
          <div class="mb-2">
            {{ author }}
          </div>
          <div class="mb-0">
            le {{ created }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body p-2">
      {{ content.field_article_commentaire }}
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-start pt-0">
      <div class="mt-3 mr-3">
        {{ content.flag_report_comment }}
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3 mr-3">
        {{ content.links }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Here is the current view of my comments :

https://ibb.co/QF051yV

I would like to display the date like this :

https://ibb.co/QCQbmG2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig's [date extension](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/date.html) does exactly what you ask:

```
{{ created | time_diff }}
```

However, this extension isn't in Drupal by default, assuming you're using Composer you need to add this extension to your project by running:

```
composer require twig/extensions
```